# Jquery popstate not working properly in Safari 7

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, safari, popstate

It's hard to find issues with Safari 7, but I've got a weird one. I'm using `pushstate` and `popstate` to modify the browser history for an ajax content loader code I've written. The code works fine with the exception of the `popstate` code which work in every browser **except Safari 7+** . Works fine in Safari 6 and lower.

```
var popped = ('state' in window.history), initialURL = location.href;
$(window).bind('popstate', function(event){
var initialPop = !popped && location.href == initialURL;
popped = true;
    console.log(event.state);
if ( initialPop ) return;
var state = event.originalEvent.state;
$("#loading").show();
$('#contentwrapper').fadeOut('normal').hide().load(state.url + " #contentwrapper > *").fadeIn('slow');
$("#loading").fadeOut();
});
```

The script works fine in all browsers. In Safari 7, the **page** loads incorrectly. The normally hidden `#loading` div is visible, and the normally visible `#contentwrapper` div is hidden. Also getting console error:

```
TypeError: 'null' is not an object (evaluating 'state.url')
```

Comment: don't know if it will help you now....safari throws a pop state initially when the page loads which is quite different from other browsers...